# AS3 tweener animation jerking

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

I currently have a grid of sprites that contain bitmap data (photographs) as children of a container sprite. I'm using [this](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) tweener library to move the container sprite to centre an image. My issue is that at the end of the animation it jerks a little. This only happens the first time you move to an image, the second time it's very smooth. I was wondering if anyone has had this problem before or if it's a buffer problem is there a way to force everything into the flash buffer? It's not dynamically loading the images before animating them, they're all loaded at the beginning.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to say without seeing code, but I would look into two things:

1. Delay the first animation using the tween lib's delay feature, or with a Timer.  There might be something executing at the same time as the animation the first time around, and this is a quick way to see if it's the case.
2. Look into the container sprite's **.cacheAsBitmap** property. Regardless of the sprite's (bitmap) contents, this settings still can effect how a sprite moves / animates. Tween libraries may set this property behind the scenes.  Try explicitly setting it to true or false before your animation.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

From the little information you provided, all I can reason is that the second time the bitmap data has been cached & does not require to load it from memory. In that case the **cacheAsBitmap** property will definitely help.

Also if the above was the case, Blitting is the best way to go. learn more about blitting, [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html).

Comment: Thanks,cacheAsBitmap fixed it up. Thanks for the blitting link as well!